# Stripe error: "you can only make test charges right now"

Tags: stripe-payments

Stripe.js won't process my test payments. It's giving the error:
`you can only make test charges right now`.

What causes this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that my app was running in its production configuration and was using my `live` key in the Stripe form. Switching to the `test` key fixed the error.